# How to properly make this js snippet content agnostic?

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii

This works:

http://jsfiddle.net/4XQ2u/16/

However, among other bad things on the code, you may notice that I heavily add things like:

```
val('Remove Translation Fields');
```

and

```
val('Add Translation Fields');
```

Let's imagine that we need to re-use this script, this functionality, this interaction and that, instead of add or remove "translation" we wish to, Add or remove "more details", or add or remove "any other fieldset of any sort" - Or, for instance, let's imagine that we need to translate this application... 
A poor javascript like this, would force us to each time our application content change, we have to edit this javascript accordingly.

I'm fairly new to javascript (jquery) and programming in general, so I would like to ask:

**What alternatives do one have to make a variation of this script content agnostic ?**

If relevant, please note this is part of a PHP MVC application using Yii framework.

Comment: I would handle localisation within your PHP and then just show/hide elements with your JavaScript.

Comment: @JamesSouth so, instead of val('Remove Translation Fields'), what should we have ? - Please note this is a very basic question because I'm fairly new here.

Comment: I would probably have two buttons. One of them hidden. and then toggle the visibility of those buttons. That way you are editing content only in the page.

Comment: @JamesSouth so, instead of val, I may instead use show hide. May `toggle` be an option then? I mean, imagine that at some stage, both fieldsets will be "visible" will toggle know that, at the "first click" he should NOT display but instead hide ?

Comment: Actually yeah. jQuery is ace for stuff like that. Check out this sample. http://jsfiddle.net/TXDu4/

Comment: @JamesSouth Can you please elaborate it as an answer on SO please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would go about it is to handle content in your html only and any localisation i.e language, currency, numeracy in your PHP [info here](http://www.codeforest.net/translate-and-localize-your-web-application-with-php-and-gettext). JavaScript could then be used to manipulate the markup to perform behavioural tasks thus keeping your concerns nicely separated.

For example. In your instance I would simply have two buttons, one of them hidden on load using css and toggle them based on the events that take place in your page.

I've updated you original fiddle to reflect some simple changes [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4XQ2u/46/).

Comment: I've tried your kindly provided code. I still have issues however. Again, I'm wondering if toggle can fit here. On some cases, "two" fieldsets can be rendered at the beginning. If you edit your fiddle and you add "two" fieldsets there, you will see notice the non-sense of the buttons. Is this a logic issue, or a toggle limitation for this scenario ? http://jsfiddle.net/4XQ2u/43/

Comment: The limitation is based on the line `if($('#localized fieldset').length === 1)` Toggle is only really changing the visibility of the buttons so it is essentially a logic issue. I've updated my link to fix that.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed was a logic issue. I end up changing it with a lot of toggles. :s

Comment: Check my new sample linked in my answer. No more toggles than the original.